# Match SDL 1.2's default palette with SDL_CreateRGBSurface()?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm porting [a SDL 1.2 program](https://web.archive.org/web/20171007163225/http://adam.ierymenko.name/nanopond.shtml) ([repository](https://github.com/adamierymenko/nanopond)) that uses 8-bit indexed color surfaces to SDL2.

Unfortunately `SDL_CreateRGBSurface()` sets an all-white, 256-entry palette by default for 8 bpp surfaces instead of the RGB884 palette that `SDL_SetVideoMode()` sets in SDL 1.2.

How can I get set a palette that matches the default palette from a SDL 1.2 `SDL_SetVideoMode(..., ..., 8, SDL_SWSURFACE)` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_SetPaletteColors()` and tables derived from SDL 1.2's `SDL_SetVideoMode()` output give me this snippet:

```
surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, 100, 100, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Uint8 r[8] = { 0, 36, 73, 109, 146, 182, 219, 255 };
Uint8 g[8] = { 0, 36, 73, 109, 146, 182, 219, 255 };
Uint8 b[4] = { 0, 85, 170, 255 };
int curColor = 0;
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
for( unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; ++j )
for( unsigned int k = 0; k < 4; ++k )
{
    SDL_Color color = { r[i], g[j], b[k], 255 };
    SDL_SetPaletteColors( surface->format->palette, &color, curColor, 1 );
    curColor++;
}
```